# Adding a generic service to cluster from powershell

Tags: powershell, generics, service, cluster-computing, failover

I'm a **newbie** in clustering and I'm trying to create a generic service to a cluster using PowerShell. I can add it without any issues using the GUI, but for some reason I cannot add it from PowerShell.

Following the first example from the documentation for [Add-ClusterGenericServiceRole](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460966.aspx), I've tried the following command:

```
Add-ClusterGenericServiceRole -ServiceName "MyService"
```

This throws the following error:

```
Static network was [network range] was not configured. Please use -StaticAddress to use this network or -IgnoreNetwork to ignore it.
```

What's the connection between the network and my service?  And why aren't these details required when creating it from the GUI?

I also tried another approach, creating the resource with:

```
Add-ClusterResrouce -Name MyService -ResourceType "Generic Serice"
```

This command succeeded but I noticed in the GUI that the ServiceName is blank, and thus the actual service cannot be started. If I could somehow change the ServiceName property it should do the trick. Again, from PowerShell I tried the following:

```
$resource = Get-ClusterResrouce "MyService"
$Resource.ServiceName = "Actual name of service" //property ServiceName cannot be found on this object.
```

I've been struggling for a couple of hours now with no luck. Is there something basic I'm missing?  I think this shouldn't be as complicated as it might look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem; I had to add a large amount of services and got stuck with the "ServiceName" as well.

First, a note on the Add-ClusterGenericServiceRole command: this is for creating the service resource and the role at the same time, as opposed to just adding the service resource to an *existing* role.

Now, the solution is that you have to set the parameter "ServiceName" with the `Set-ClusterParameter` command. You can do this for an existing service resource like this:

```
Get-ClusterResource "ServiceDisplayName" | Set-ClusterParameter -Name ServiceName -Value "ServiceName"
```

However, you probably want to create the resource with everything it needs in one go, like this:

```
Add-ClusterResource -Name "ServiceDisplayName" -Group "cluster role" -ResourceType "Generic Service" | Set-
ClusterParameter -Name ServiceName -Value "ServiceName"
```

Comment: I posted the issue, looked back for several weeks, then lost interest. I managed to fix it in the meantime (before your post) using the solution you provided. Almost two years later, I log into my account, I see an answer and i thought i might as well validate it and let others know this worked. Please accept my late "thank you for your answer"!